# SQL error when trying to create database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/#disqus_thread 
to create login for my android app and I am stuck on step 2. I clicked on the SQL section in phpmyadmin, and pasted the code:

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

and it says there is a syntax error near 'use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   uid int(1' at line 3

I've never worked with php so I don't know whats going on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close each statement. I think this should resolve your issue.

```
create database android_api;

use android_api;

create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

Also this SQL, not PHP. `PHPmyadmin` is a UI to interact with a mysql DB. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Yes this fixed the syntax error. Thanks and sorry for my unclear post!

Comment: No problem. Please mark this as accepted when the time has passed. In the future please include your code and format it when posting, http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting.